# TCL to JSON : Writing JSON output using huddle in single line

Tags: json, tcl

Let us consider a tcl data as follows:

```
set arr {a {{c 1} {d {2 2 2} e 3}} b {{f 4 g 5}}}
```

Converted into Json format using huddle module:

```
set json_arr [huddle jsondump [huddle compile {dict * {list {dict d list}}} $arr]]
puts $json_arr
```

Json fromatted array:

```
{
  "a": [
    {"c": 1},
    {
      "d": [
        2,
        2,
        2
      ],
      "e": 3
    }
  ],
  "b": [{
      "f": 4,
      "g": 5
    }]
}
```

Writing in a single line:

```
set json_arr [huddle jsondump [huddle compile {dict * {list {dict d list}}} $arr] {} {}]
puts $json_arr
```

Updated Json formatted array:

```
{"a":[{"c":1},{"d":[2,2,2],"e":3}],"b":[{"f":4,"g":5}]}
```

What is the meaning of {} {} here?

Can I use the same for single line in case of output by json and json::write module ?

Answer (score 1):

The last three, optional, arguments to `jsondump` are `offset`, `newline`, and `begin_offset`. You can use those to specify strings that are to be used to format the output string. If you don’t specify them, default strings will be used.

If you do specify them, you need to follow the protocol for optional arguments, i.e. if you want to specify `begin_offset`, you need to specify `offset` and `newline` too, etc. In this case, `offset` and `newline` are specified to be empty strings, and `begin_offset` uses its default value.

Try invoking `jsondump` with dummy values to get an idea of how they are used:

```
% huddle jsondump [huddle compile {dict * {list {dict d list}}} $arr] <A> <B> <C>
{<B><C><A>"a": [<B><C><A><A>{"c": 1},<B><C><A><A>{<B><C><A><A><A>"d": [<B><C><A><A><A><A>2,<B><C><A><A><A><A>2,<B><C><A><A><A><A>2<B><C><A><A><A>],<B><C><A><A><A>"e": 3<B><C><A><A>}<B><C><A>],<B><C><A>"b": [{<B><C><A><A><A>"f": 4,<B><C><A><A><A>"g": 5<B><C><A><A>}]<B><C>}
```

A `newline` and a `begin_offset` string is inserted around each component, and one or more `offset` strings are inserted before a component to reflect the indentation level.

`json::write` uses the `indented` and `aligned` subcommands to customize formatting.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Your answers are helping me a lot. I have few more queries related to TCL to JSON conversion. I ask that query in a new question.   Thank you.

Comment: Link for huddle jsondump https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html#21